# MySQL: Can I build an IN clause combining both results from a SELECT statement and a hard-coded list?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I'm trying to build a query that looks like:

```
SELECT p.* FROM Person p 
WHERE p.name IN ('jim', 'sally') OR p.name IN (SELECT name FROM goodNames)
```

Now this query works fine, but it's a performance critical query so I'd like to be able to combine the two IN clauses like:

```
SELECT p.* FROM Person p 
WHERE p.name IN ('jim', 'sally', (SELECT name FROM goodNames))
```

(this gives error: Subquery returns more than 1 row)

Note: 'jim' and 'sally' may either be or not be in `goodNames` and I would like both the results from `goodNames` AND those from the provided list

Is there a way to do that in MySQL?

Thanks!

Comment: No, you cannot do that.  Your original method is a good approach.

Comment: You original query is fine. You need to investigate why you have slowness. What is your query execution plan? What indexes you have on the table? How many distinct names selected by sub-query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When OR's impact index performance, which is what I would imagine your concern would be, you can take the less than ideal tactic of converting them to UNIONs, like so:

```
SELECT p.* FROM Person p 
WHERE p.name IN ('jim', 'sally')
UNION
SELECT p.* FROM Person p 
WHERE p.name IN (SELECT name FROM goodNames)
```

It's not ideal, especially for complicated queries, as it involves duplicating most of the query (and having to maintain those duplicates across changes); but when it is important enough for performance, it is a fairly standard solution to take.

*Due to the higher "maintenance cost", I only recommend doing this if you actually observe performance issues with the original version.*

---

some other clumsy alternatives....

```
WHERE p.name IN (
   SELECT name FROM goodNames 
   UNION SELECT 'jim' 
   UNION SELECT 'sally'
)
```

or

insert static list elements into a temporary table, then

```
WHERE p.name IN (
   SELECT name FROM goodNames 
   UNION SELECT name FROM staticNames
)
```

---

Oh, haha, one more (you're back to OR with this one, but it is an alternative that may or may not take better advantage of indexes somehow):

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM Person p 
LEFT JOIN goodNames AS g ON p.name = g.name
WHERE g.name IS NOT NULL OR p.name IN ('jim', 'sally')
```

Comment: I believe one should investigate why there is some slowness with query instead of converting it into UNION. There is nothing wrong with the original query and modern query optimizer should deal with it with no issues. However, it might be too many results returned by subquery and so no plan with index by name is available. As a result full table scan and slow query. UNION will NOT solve the issue.

Comment: @fifonik Obviously slowness should be investigated when it is unexpected, but using `OR` in MySQL conditions is known to impact MySQL's ability to take advantage of indexes effectively; until recent versions, `IN (list)` had similar impacts. So most likely in this case, once the question had been researched with EXPLAIN, the question would have just been asking "why isn't MySQL using my index". _Hence why I prefaced my answer the way I did._

Comment: This is the answer I both expected and am sad to see, thanks though!

Answer (score -1):

You can acheive this in a single query through left join of Person and gooNames table:

```
SELECT p.* FROM Person p LEFT JOIN goodNames g ON p.name = g.name WHERE p.name IN ('jim', 'sally') OR g.name IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: OP's issue is that `jim` and `sally` aren't in `goodNames` but they would also like those results pulled from `Person`. This doesn't solve that issue.

Comment: You have misunderstood the question, please update your answer so it's relevant to what is being asked.

Comment: Yes understood the issue with my previous answer. Updated.